# How often does Bitcoin connect to the fallback nodes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, fallback-nodes, connection, peers, nodes

Does the standard client have a preference for connecting to fallback nodes (for example, by trying to have at least 1 connection to such node at all times), or are they treated like any other nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin only connects to them specially when you don't have enough nodes, and then it will disconnect as soon as the seednodes give you a nodelist. Bitcoin might choose to connect to seednodes as regular peers as well, but they're not given any preference.

Comment: can we make Bitcoin to not disconnect from fallback nodes ?